# Why Rust compiler doesn't consider Box<FileRotate<_>> as valid a implementation for Box<(dyn std::io::Write + Send + 'static)?

Tags: logging, rust

I am attempting to combine a rotating log with `fern`, by chaining a boxed `FileRotate` instance (from `file-rotate` crate) with a `fern` `Dispatch` instance, but can't seem to satisfy the compiler. Here is the code snippet:

```rust
let log= Box::new(
    FileRotate::new(
        "log/output.log",
        CountSuffix::new(2),
        ContentLimit::Lines(10),
        Compression::None));

fern::Dispatch::new()
    .level(LevelFilter::Debug)
    .chain(log)
    .apply()?;
```

The compiler disagrees, with the following error:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fern::Output: From<Box<FileRotate<CountSuffix>>>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:101:16
    |
101 |         .chain(log)
    |          ----- ^^^ the trait `From<Box<FileRotate<CountSuffix>>>` is not implemented for `fern::Output`
    |          |
    |          required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <fern::Output as From<&'static (dyn log::Log + 'static)>>
              <fern::Output as From<Box<(dyn log::Log + 'static)>>>
              <fern::Output as From<Box<(dyn std::io::Write + Send + 'static)>>>
              <fern::Output as From<Dispatch>>
            and 6 others
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<fern::Output>` for `Box<FileRotate<CountSuffix>>`
note: required by a bound in `Dispatch::chain`
   --> /Users/l203663/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/fern-0.6.0/src/builders.rs:195:21
    |
195 |     pub fn chain<T: Into<Output>>(mut self, logger: T) -> Self {
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Dispatch::chain`
```

However, the `FileRotate` struct implements both `Write` and `Send`, as documented [here](https://docs.rs/file-rotate/latest/file_rotate/struct.FileRotate.html#trait-implementations) and [here](https://docs.rs/file-rotate/latest/file_rotate/struct.FileRotate.html#synthetic-implementations).

The closest implementation proposed by the compiler is IMO:

```
From<Box<(dyn std::io::Write + Send + 'static)>>
```

- Is the issue caused by the `'static` lifetime? In which case, how could I solve this?
- If not, what could possibly cause the issue?

---

Crates in use:

```
log = "0.4.14"
fern = "0.6.0"
file-rotate = "0.5.3"
```

Comment: Does explicitly annotating `log`'s type as `Box<(dyn std::io::Write + Send + 'static)>` give any useful information?

Comment: Thanks @SolomonUcko, that seems to work. However I found the `as` construct cleaner, as found in the voted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not certain that this is all of the problem (not having used `fern`) but since the input parameter to `chain()` is generic, it won't automatically coerce your `Box<FileRotate>` to a `Box<dyn Write + Send>`, so you have to do that explicitly:

```rust
.chain(log as Box<dyn Write + Send>)
```

You do not need to specify `'static` because that is the default for all `Box<dyn ...>` (but not `&dyn ...`).

Comment: As you mentioned it, the `chain`method has the following signature: `pub fn chain<T: Into<Output>>(self, logger: T) -> Self`. Your statement about Rust not being able to coerce from a generic type makes sense, although I could not find in in the online documentation. I may have overlooked it.